# Why can't I dismiss kivy popup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I created an application where, on start, a pop-up window appears asking for login credentials.
After providing the right credentials, this pop-up should close, so the "main window" behind it is accessible.

main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import  Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1024')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '768')


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class LoginPopup(Screen):  # Popup Window
    def login_popup(dt):  # Function to call Popup Window
        show = LoginPopup()
        popupWindow = Popup(title="Please log in", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 125),
                            auto_dismiss=False)
        popupWindow.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


class MainApp(App):
    def dismiss(self):
        self.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(LoginPopup.login_popup, 1)  # Loading the login popup 1 second after initialising
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
<LoginPopup>:
    id: popupWindow
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            Label:
                pos: (0,40)
                text: "Password: "
                text_size: self.size

            TextInput:
                pos: (80,35)
                size_hint_y: (.8)
                size_hint_x: (.785)
                password: True
                id: password
                multiline: False
        Button:
            id: login_button
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: 1,0.5
            pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0.1}
            on_release:
                root.login_popup.popupWindow.dismiss() if password.text == "XXX" else None
                print(password.text)
```

Inside the my.kv I want to dismiss the pop-up with `root.login_popup.popupWindow.dismiss() if password.text == "XXX" else None` but I get an error that "'function' object has no attribute 'popupWindow'

Is this because the "popupWindow" object is instantiated with another name? How can I fix this?

(I took out some of the my.kv code of other screens as they are not in use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `popupWindow` variable in your code is a local variable to the `login_popup()` method. You can make that a class level variable by changing your `LoginPopup` class to:

```
class LoginPopup(Screen):  # Popup Window
    popupWindow = None

    def login_popup(dt):  # Function to call Popup Window
        show = LoginPopup()
        LoginPopup.popupWindow = Popup(title="Please log in", content=show, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 125),
                            auto_dismiss=False)
        LoginPopup.popupWindow.open()
```

Then you can access it in your `kv` as:

```
        on_release:
            root.popupWindow.dismiss() if password.text == "XXX" else None
            print(password.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, easier than I expected. If I want to change the color of the TextInput in <LoginPopup> after clicking the Button, how do I access the TextInput?

Comment: You can access it the same way. For example, in the same `on_release` block in your `kv`, you can add `password.background_color=[1,0,0,1] if password.text != "XXX" else [1,1,1,1]`.